# Necesito desplegar todos los registros iguales desde Android Studio con SQLite

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo una base de datos en una app en la cual tengo registrados los Nombres(VARCHAR) y un RFC(VARCHAR) de usuarios. Tengo que hacer una búsqueda ingresando un parámetro en las dos tablas (Nombre y RFC), si hay registros repetidos, la lista me tiene que desplegar todos los registros iguales al parámetro que inserto. Pero mi código solo muestra al primer registro que sea igual al parámetro.

```
private void consultarSql() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=conn.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] parametros={campoId.getText().toString() , campoId.getText().toString() };
    Usuario usuario=null;

    try {
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT "
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_ID+","
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+","
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_TELEFONO+ ","
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_RFC+ ","
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_DIRECCION+","
                +Utilidades.CAMPO_PASSWORD+
                " FROM "+Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO+" WHERE "+Utilidades.CAMPO_RFC+ " = ? OR " +Utilidades.CAMPO_NOMBRE+" = ? ",parametros);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
            usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            usuario.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
            usuario.setTelefono(cursor.getString(2));
            usuario.setRFC(cursor.getString(3));
            usuario.setDireccion(cursor.getString(4));
            usuario.setPassword(cursor.getString(5));

            //System.out.println("Usuario encontrado con nombre: "+ usuario.getNombre());
            listaUsuario.add(usuario);



    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No se encontro",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a lo que comentas veo lo que hace falta es iterar el contenido del objeto **cursor** ya que con la query que ejecutas el objeto ya tendría todos los datos, quedaría así:

```
        if( cursor.moveToFirst() )
        {
            do{
                usuario = new Usuario();
                usuario.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                usuario.setNombre(cursor.getString(1));
                usuario.setTelefono(cursor.getString(2));
                usuario.setRFC(cursor.getString(3));
                usuario.setDireccion(cursor.getString(4));
                usuario.setPassword(cursor.getString(5));

                listaUsuario.add(usuario);
            }while( cursor.moveToNext() );  
        }
```

Saludos!